# Running nose with a large number of test-data files

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I want to write some tests for a web scraper. I want to use a lot of test web pages, but I'm not sure exactly how to get nose (or another unit testing framework) to do what I need without a huge amount of duplicate code.

My problem is that I want to test a lot of different pages and I'm not sure how to do this using nose. This is roughly what I want to do:

```
class TestPage(object):
    def setup(self):
        with open('test_data/page.html', 'r') as f:
            html = f.read()
        self.scraper = Scraper(html)
```

This would be fine if the only page I wanted to test were 'page.html'. But I have hundreds of pages to test. I could duplicate the class and each time change both the class's name and the filename of the path, but this would obviously be ridiculous.

I thought of putting code in setup to create separate Scraper objects for each page and store them in a list in the test object. I could then have the test methods operate on each Scraper object. But I think I'd run into problems with keeping each test isolated and getting separate messages from nose.

I also tried to subclass a base test class and pass the path to **init**, but this creates problems for nose.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to solve this using nose, another approach to take, or any reading that might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

based on your code sample, you just need a class factory:

```
def make_test(page)
    class TestPage(object):
        def setup(self):
            with open(page, 'r') as f:
                html = f.read()
            self.scraper = Scraper(html)
     return TestPage
```

Now you can just run over a list of pages and make one test for each one:

```
for page in list_of_pages:
    Test = make_test(page)
    Test().run()
```

I'm not sure if that's how you run a nose test but It would be a full fledged class so you could do whatever you would normally do with it.

You could store all of your tests pages in one directory so that you could just loop over the files in the directory and get your list of pages that way. All you would have to do to create a new test is save the html in the given directory. Is that about what you were looking for?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's not going to help with nose since the factory requires an argument and nose needs to be run with no arguments.

Comment: @user26988 From reading the [docs](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.2/writing_tests.html), I think you want to put the code that I've shown you in a test module and use a test generator to produce the test cases. So put the `for` loop in a function called `test_pages` and change the line `Test().run()` to `yield Test`.

Comment: @aaronasterling I somehow didn't see the second half of your answer before so I was responding only to the first code block. I'm trying to mock up something similar, but I'm not familiar with the run() method. From what I can tell, it has to do with threads? I keep getting an attribute error for run().

Comment: @user269288 I just put `run` in to illustrate the idea. I don't use nose so I don't really know.  It's not supposed to be a real function. How do you usually run a test case when you need to do it manually? Just do that. Or read the docs that I linked to.

Comment: @user269288 Specifically the section on _test modules_ and _test generators_.

Comment: @aaronasterling Ah, sorry. There were google hits for run() and I filled in some gaps I shouldn't have. I'm interested in nose because I want to run nosetests from the command line. I don't think generators will work here because they treat the yielded callable as the test function, whereas I just want to set up in class and have nose detect it later. I might be able to write a plugin to handle this, but I think I'll use nose later and for now just keep my own tests. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @aaronasterling Also, what's the etiquette for upvoting here? You've been very helpful and I appreciate your time, but this answer doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @user269288 If the answer doesn't solve your problem, don't ever accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Freshen (https://github.com/rlisagor/freshen) via nose seems to be the best answer.

Just write feature files, then you just have to add a scenario per URL to test.